Was Macbeth considering murdering Duncan before Lady Macbeth encouraged him to?
In Macbeth, after announcing that he will go be a harbinger for Duncan and make things ready for him at Inverness, Macbeth says this aside to himself:

Macbeth
[Aside]
The Prince of Cumberland! that is a step
On which I must fall down, or else o'erleap,
For in my way it lies. Stars, hide your fires;
Let not light see my black and deep desires:
The eye wink at the hand; yet let that be
Which the eye fears, when it is done, to see.
Macbeth, Act 1, Scene 4, Amsco Literature Program edition

The previous owner of my copy has annotated this paragraph with the note that he is "horrified about murdering Duncan". However, my understanding was that at this point in time, Macbeth wasn't yet planning to kill Duncan, but to assume the throne after his death by other means. It is only in the next scene that Lady Macbeth convinces Macbeth that he should kill Duncan.
Was Macbeth actually considering murdering Duncan at this point? If not, what does "The eye wink at the hand; yet let that be / Which the eye fears, when it is done, to see" mean?

At this early point in the play it's not possible to determine Macbeth's attitude toward killing Duncan. In this particular scene he is considering commiting wicked deeds, but we can't be sure what, exactly, he's considering, and his target is Malcolm, Duncan's son, whom Duncan has named his heir and the Prince of Cumberland.
So when Macbeth says

The Prince of Cumberland! that is a step
On which I must fall down, or else o'erleap,

He is saying that, to become king, he must bypass Malcom somehow. Of course, it's pretty hard to "bypass" a named heir without doing something pretty nefarious, so:

The eye wink at the hand; yet let that be
Which the eye fears, when it is done, to see.

He is saying that he does not want to see what wicked deed his hand might he doing, but once it's finished, he'll be forced to look and deal with the consequences.
This might well mean murder, but it might not. It could conceivably be something less drastic, like a plot to frame or exile Malcolm or otherwise estrange him from his father. We don't know and Macbeth doesn't tell us. But whatever Macbeth had in mind, while nefarious, the target is Malcolm, not Duncan himself.
It feels like Macbeth is simply too close to Duncan, both on a personal level and in the sense of gratitude, for him to think about targeting the King at this point. Through this whole scene, Duncan has lavished Macbeth with praise. On a human level its pretty hard to turn around and plot to kill someone who's been so kind and generous to you directly, and all the more so when he's your sworn sovereign lord. As such, it requires his wife's goading to push Macbeth into taking that extra step.
Consider the following scene, in which Lady Macbeth is reading out a letter sent by her husband. It's not clear if we get the full letter or merely the end, but either way, it says nothing about killing Duncan. It's Lady Macbeth who implies that Macbeth will need to kill the king in order to fulfil the Witches' prophecies, and she famously says her husband:

It is too full o’ th’ milk of human kindness

To do the foul deeds required. So she doesn't think he's capable of it, at this point, either. And when Macbeth arrives and she posits this plot to him, his response is:

We’ll speak about this further

Which, again, is equivocal. It could mean he's made up his mind to kill Duncan, but it could also mean that he's still unwilling to face up to that possibility. He certainly seems unwilling in the discussion that follows, needing fierce goading from his wife before he will commit to murder.
Finally, I feel it's also worth noting that a key theme that develops through Macbeth is that of guilt and the result is a degree of sympathy for the villains. If that were indeed Shakespeare's aim, showing Macbeth as immediately jumping to kill his king would undermine what sympathy the audience could develop for him.

It’s in the nature of a play that we only have the characters’ speeches, so that we have to deduce their thoughts, feelings and motives. This opens the door to multiple interpretations: maybe Macbeth was only anticipating gaining the crown of Scotland “holily”, or maybe he started considering the murder as soon as he heard with prophecy. Let’s look at the evidence for each of these interpretations.
Murder was Lady Macbeth’s idea

There is no explicit mention of the murder of Duncan by Macbeth prior to his meeting Lady Macbeth in 1.5. He may hint at a “horrid image” in his thoughts, or at “black and deep desires”, but perhaps in each case he means something other than murder.

Macbeth sends a letter to his wife (1.5) in which he sets down the witches’ prophecies in writing. If he had considered murdering Duncan he would surely not have done this, in case the letter fell into other hands.

Lady Macbeth says (1.5) that her husband is “full of the milk of human kindness”, that he would rather achieve the crown “holily”, and that he would “not play false”, unless she “pours her spirits in his ear”.


Macbeth intended murder all along

Macbeth is described by a soldier (1.2) as having “smoked with bloody execution” in the fight with the rebels, and “unseamed him [Macdonwald] from the nave to the chops, and fixed his head upon our battlements”. Clearly Macbeth is well-accustomed to killing people.

Immediately upon hearing the witches prophecy that he will be king (1.3), Macbeth says in an aside, “why do I yield to that suggestion whose horrid image doth unfix my hair?” and then, “my thought, whose murder yet is but fantastical”. This indicates that the idea of murdering Duncan in order to claim the throne of Scotland has just occurred to him, and even as he rejects the idea as “fantastical” he qualifies the rejection with a “yet”, leaving open the possibility that at some future date the fantastical may become real.

In a second aside (1.3), he says, “If chance will have me king, why, chance may crown me
Without my stir.” This indicates that he has been considering what “stir” (action) he might take to gain the crown, even if he hopes that he won’t have to do it.

Duncan says (1.4) of the former Thane of Cawdor, “there’s no art to find the mind’s construction in the face”. This is a case of dramatic irony—the audience are meant to apply this to Macbeth (the new Thane of Cawdor) and consider what treachery he is currently concealing.

Macbeth says in an aside (1.4), “Stars, hide your fires! Let not light see my black and deep desires. The eye wink at the hand, yet let that be, which the eye fears, when it is done, to see.” What are these “black and deep desires” that he wishes no-one to see, if not the desire to claim the throne by murdering its current occupant?

The first thing that Macbeth says on meeting his wife is, “Duncan comes here tonight.” This indicates that the opportunity for murder is uppermost in his mind, and that there is no time to waste on pleasantries.

When his wife asks him when Duncan “goes hence”, Macbeth replies, “Tomorrow, as he purposes.” The phrase “as he purposes” hints that the speaker purposes otherwise.

When Macbeth is king, how does he approach difficulties and obstacles? When the prophecy concerning Banquo’s descendants starts to worry him, he has the man murdered (3.1). When Macduff flees to England, he has Lady Macduff and her son murdered (4.2). Murder seems to be a solution that comes very readily to Macbeth’s mind after he is king, so why not before?


Synthesis
The evidence comes down fairly heavily on the side of Macbeth considering, or even planning, murder, from 1.3 onwards. But then how do we accommodate the points raised in support of the other interpretation?
The lack of any explicit statement of intent to murder Duncan is no difficulty. Macbeth knows that this is wrong, and avoiding direct statement is a way of dealing with an internal moral conflict. Macbeth fears being suspected, and so he is careful not to give his plans away, even in soliloquy. Note that the same considerations apply to Lady Macbeth: her statements are no clearer than her husband’s, as discussed in this answer.
The letter is equivocal. A guilty Macbeth might be more likely to consider the consequences of the letter falling into the wrong hands, but there is nothing stopping an innocent Macbeth from doing the same. In any case, the letter is to some extent an artificial device to resolve the dramatic problem of bringing Lady Macbeth up to date with events that have already been depicted on stage, as discussed in this answer, so we shouldn’t put too much emphasis on it.
In the “milk of human kindness” speech, Lady Macbeth says only that she fears her husband will not go through with the murder, not that he has not considered it. Her persuasive words will stiffen his resolve, she says, not broach the subject. See this answer for Friedrich Bodenstedt’s comment that “in the whole drama we find no trace of this milk of human kindness”.

This is an excellent summary - better than my answer - but I don't think your points 7 & 8 hold much water.. 7 could well be a figure of speech, like someone saying "he plans to go tomorrow" and doesn't carry any implications. 8 always felt to me like a warning on what happens when someone violates a taboo: once broken, it becomes easier to do so again, and again.

Point #6 seems pretty weak to me. If I know that someone is coming by later, one of the first things I'm going to do on seeing my spouse/partner is tell them. I might engage in some pleasantries first: "Hi dear, how was your day?," etc. but it's a play, which would leave out such trivialities. And in any case a production might have the Macbeths kissing first, or some inaudible words passing between them.

Typo: did you mean "the witches' prophecy that" or "the witches prophesy that"? The meaning is pretty much the same either way, but the error brought this exacting reader to a sudden halt. ;-)

The answer by verbose builds upon the previous answers and provides (in my view) the best response, so my contribution is merely a deeper exploration of two elements of Macbeth's murderous decision that may not have received enough attention.
Moral choice: foul vs fair
The most essential epithet of the play is delivered in the most dramatic fashion, in just seven short words, in the very first minute of the play. Shakespeare doesn't muck around. The audience is immediately silenced with "Lightning and Thunder" before anyone sets foot on stage: pay attention folks! Then the three witches enter: for those times, a genuinely terrifying sight! A short, evil incantation ensues, and they finish with a chorus of

Fair is foul, and foul is fair:
Hover through the fog and filthy air.

Here's the substance of the whole play: "fair" and "foul" are interchangeable. It's a monstrous statement. Surely two such moral opposites can never be reconciled?
Significantly, the witches tie Macbeth to this epithet when they say they'll meet him on the heath. Scene II then gives us further context, establishing that Macbeth is "fair": according to the King, he's "valiant", a "worthy gentleman", "noble".
The critical Scene III, on the heath, opens with the stage instruction "Thunder": pay attention, audience! The terrifying witches enter, describe some unspeakable activities and plans, reveal a dead man's thumb (horror!), and complete their "charm" as Macbeth and Banquo enter. And what are the central character's first words in this play?

So foul and fair a day I have not seen.

Even the most inattentive audience member couldn't miss this reference.
When the witches hail Macbeth "that shalt be king hereafter", Banquo comments on Macbeth surprisingly strong reaction. Had Macbeth already been coveting the crown? No: there's nothing before this point to suggest so. Rather, I think the actor could validly portray this moment as if he'd just been stung, as if the evil seed had just then been planted.
Half a minute later, Banquo says Macbeth "seems rapt withal" – which leaves us in no doubt that Macbeth is now thinking about the concept of being king. (Stage direction: perhaps he's now staring into the distance, chin in his hand?) In case the idea of a seed being planted isn't clear enough, Banquo asks the witches to tell him his own fate

If you can look into the seeds of time,
And say which grain will grow.

The witches do just that, but when Macbeth turns to ask them about his own future, they vanish. He and Banquo marvel at what they've heard, before Angus and Ross enter to hail Macbeth as Thane of Cawdor.
We already know from Scene II that the previous Thane had committed foul treason against the King and has been stripped of his title, now conferred on fair Macbeth, as the witches had foretold. It's as if Macbeth has been promoted to a corrupted title.
Macbeth's reaction? It's certainly not revulsion at the act of treason; rather, it's a cold calculation: "Glamis, and Thane of Cawdor: The greatest is behind." If those two titles/prophesies are the "greatest" and they're "behind", then what's ahead (i.e. realising the third prophesy, the crown) must be the least. That foul seed has taken root, and is growing.
Moral choice: weakness vs moral fibre
From this point on, we see a weak man with no moral fibre, captive to his worst desires but too timid to take action.
In another aside (still in Scene III), Macbeth ponders how the prophesies can be both "ill" and "good" – in other words, both foul and fair. In particular, if receiving his new titles is good,

why do I yield to that suggestion
Whose horrid image doth unfix my hair,
And make my seated heart knock at my ribs,
Against the use of nature? Present fears
Are less than horrible imaginings.
My thought, whose murder yet is but fantastical,
Shakes so my single state of man
That function is smother’d in surmise,
And nothing is but what is not.

The horrid image, the horrible imaginings, the thought, the fantasy – they all revolve around a single, dreadful word, which he says out loud to the audience: murder. Yet he also reveals what a jelly he has become: "why do I yield" (a passive, submissive action), "unfixed hair" (like a madman), knocking heart, his entire state so shaken that "function is smother’d in surmise" (he can no longer act decisively) and he has lost touch with reality. Banquo again remarks "Look, how our partner’s rapt", and Macbeth makes the telling aside,

If chance will have me king, why chance may crown me
Without my stir.

Ah, what a relief! No need to be decisive or take action: the kingdom may just fall in his lap.
There's no end of vacillating, of deferrals ("we will speak further"), of about-turns ("We will proceed no further"), of quaking doubts. He finally murders his King as if sleepwalking, and on his return he tells Lady Macbeth he heard a voice say "Macbeth does murder sleep". He keeps prattling away as if he's lost his mind, causing his wife to berate him: "You do unbend your noble strength to think / So brainsickly of things."
Malcolm as a moral comparison
It's worth comparing Macbeth's weakness and moral emptiness with Malcolm's reaction in Act IV, Sc. III. Malcolm and Macduff are lamenting Scotland's fall to a tyrant, and Malcolm enumerates Macbeth's sins. He then describes how his own "most ill-compos’d affection" renders him unfit to be King: "better Macbeth / Than such an one to reign." Macduff tries to downplay these desires, but finally Malcolm blurts it out:

But I have none: the king-becoming graces,
As justice, verity, temp’rance, stableness,
Bounty, perseverance, mercy, lowliness,
Devotion, patience, courage, fortitude,
I have no relish of them; but abound
In the division of each several crime,
Acting it many ways. Nay, had I power, I should
Pour the sweet milk of concord into hell,
Uproar the universal peace, confound
All unity on earth.

Macduff despairs: "O Scotland, Scotland!" Malcolm says that's what I am: am I fit to govern? Macduff: "Fit to govern? / No, not to live." He bemoans how such a great king and queen could have produced such a son, and that Malcolm's words have banished him – and any hope – from Scotland.
This is the reality check Malcolm needed. He is, of course, nothing like the monster he just described himself as.

Macduff, this noble passion,
Child of integrity, hath from my soul
Wiped the black scruples, reconcil’d my thoughts
To thy good truth and honour.

Here we see a man of genuine moral fibre, willing to reject the crown because he recognises his own potential for weakness. But he isn't weak, and he chooses to take action to fight for the good of his country as a fair (= good) man, and to defeat the foul traitor and tyrant Macbeth.

The question, and some of the answers, appear to be conflating two distinct matters:

Did the thought of murdering Duncan enter Macbeth's mind independently of Lady Macbeth?
Would he have actually murdered Duncan without her pressuring him?

The answer to the first is an unequivocal yes. Of course the thought entered his mind, as Gareth's and Tsundoku's answers have shown. But it doesn't follow that he is determined to act upon the thought. The play makes it eminently clear that he is conflicted. Here, for instance, is Macbeth arguing both sides of the matter to himself:

           He’s here in double trust:
First, as I am his kinsman and his subject,
Strong both against the deed; then, as his host,
Who should against his murderer shut the door,
Not bear the knife myself. Besides, this Duncan
Hath borne his faculties so meek, hath been
So clear in his great office, that his virtues
Will plead like angels, trumpet-tongued, against
The deep damnation of his taking-off;
And pity, like a naked newborn babe
Striding the blast, or heaven’s cherubin horsed
Upon the sightless couriers of the air,
Shall blow the horrid deed in every eye,
That tears shall drown the wind. I have no spur
To prick the sides of my intent, but only
Vaulting ambition, which o’erleaps itself
And falls on th’ other—
Shakespeare, William. Macbeth. 1606. Folger Shakespeare Library. I.7.12–28. Accessed at folger.edu 15 July 2024.

The speech breaks off right when Lady Macbeth enters. Macbeth announces to her: "We will proceed no further in this business" (line 34). She forcefully argues for the assassination, scorning Macbeth's vacillating, berating him for cowardice, and asking why he would discuss the possibility of murder with her if he were not prepared to go through with it. She says that Macbeth has promised her that he will kill Duncan, and that she herself would have upheld any similar promise had she made it:

           I have given suck, and know
How tender ’tis to love the babe that milks me.
I would, while it was smiling in my face,
Have plucked my nipple from his boneless gums
And dashed the brains out, had I so sworn as you
Have done to this.
ibid. I.vii.61–67.

There is no textual evidence that Macbeth has actually sworn to kill Duncan; in saying this, and in the horrific image of dashing the baby's brains out, Lady Macbeth is using hyperbole as a manipulative technique. Her rhetoric is effective enough that by the end of the scene, Macbeth has come around to her stated view of things.
Act I scene 7 is critical to any understanding of Macbeth's motivations. The scene makes eminently clear that while Macbeth has already thought of regicide, he is conflicted, and Lady Macbeth's words push him over the edge. This is not to let him off the hook and place the blame for the murder solely on Lady Macbeth: he could have stuck to his resolve of not proceeding further. But the play does show Macbeth and even Lady Macbeth as complex characters with conflicting drives. His conflict is most evident before the murder, hers after.
So to answer the two questions distinguished above:

Yes, the thought of murdering Duncan does enter Macbeth's mind independently of Lady Macbeth
He might not have murdered Duncan without her pressure. He still might have; but the play shows that a chief reason he does murder Duncan is that he gives in to Lady Macbeth. Any speculation about whether he would have done so without her would be just that: speculation.

It's worth pointing out that despite her bravado, Lady Macbeth herself is quite unable to murder Duncan:

           I laid their daggers ready;
He could not miss ’em. Had he not resembled
My father as he slept, I had done ’t.
ibid. II.2.15–17

She boasts of being able to kill her own suckling baby, but cannot bring herself to kill an elderly man on the grounds that he resembles her father? Macbeth and his lady are trapped in a destructive spiral: the two of them feed off each other, with the result that they are jointly responsible for a murder that they would likely have been incapable of severally.

In order to answer this question, one must look further back, namely to Act 1, scene 3, when Macbeth and Banquo encounter the Weird Sisters. The women greet Macbeth in three ways (all quotes from Braunmuller's edition):

"All hail, Macbeth! hail to thee, thane of Glamis!"
"All hail, Macbeth, hail to thee, thane of Cawdor!"
"All hail, Macbeth, thou shalt be king hereafter!"

After these greetings, Macbeth responds in a way that is not described in the First Folio's stage directions and that we can only infer from Banquo's reaction to it:

Good sir, why do you start and seem to fear
Things that do sound so fair?

He gets no verbal reaction from Macbeth and therefore addresses the Weird Sisters:

I'th'name of truth,
Are ye fantastical, (…)?

Judging by the time that elapses between the third weird sister's greeting and Macbeth's next speech, the thane of Glamis needs around half a minute to recover. Directors have interpreted this in various ways. For example, in a production by the Royal Shakespeare Company directed by Adrian Noble with Jonathan Pryce in the title role (1986–87), Macbeth fainted, as if shocked that the weird sisters had guessed a secret ambition (interview with Jonathan Pryce, Observer, 9 Nov. 1986, quoted in Bate and Rasmussen):

His extreme reaction perhaps indicated that he had not just thought about being king, but had already though about killing the king. (Rasmussen and Bate, 140)

When Macbeth is able to speak again, he says that

(…) to be king
Stands not within the prospect of belief.

When Ross and Angus tell him that the king has named him thane of Cawdor, Macbeth has a number of asides and short dialogues in which he does not show much gratitude (beyond the short "Thanks for your pains" and "I thank you gentlemen"), joy or satisfaction; instead he start thinking about something else. What he has heard are

happy prologues to the swelling act
Of the imperial theme.

"The imperial theme" means "the subject or topic of empery (= becoming not 'emperor', but king)" (Braunmuller, 116).
He is uncertain whether to interpret this "unnatural solliciting" (i.e. incitement; Braunmuller, 117) is good or ill and continues (emphasis mine):

(…) who do I yield to that suggestion,
Whose horrid image doth unfix my hair
And make my seated heart knock at my ribs
Against the use of nature? Present fears
Are less than horrible imaginings.
My thought, whose murder yet is but fantastical,
Shakes so my single state of man that function
Is smothered is surmise, (…)

As we already know, Macbeth has no legal way to the throne ("not within the prospect of belief", above), and these words suggest that he had already been thinking about a route that he himself thinks of as horrid. His mental conflict is so visible that Banquo comments,

Look how our partner's rapt.

When Macbeth adds,

If chance will have me king, why chance may crown me
Without my stir.

we should remember that he has no legal path to the throne, so only an unlikely course of events could put him there without violence. In some sources, Macbeth is Duncan's cousin, which would put him in the line of succession. In Shakespeare's play, Macbeth is Duncan's kinsman [1], but apparently not close enough to have a chance of succeeding Duncan.
When Duncan officially declares Malcolm his successor, Macbeth sees the newly named Prince of Cumberland as another obstacle on his way to the throne. At this point, this confirms his wish to become king but it also implies that he has no plans to openly seize the throne by getting rid of Duncan's family. If the latter were the case, Malcolm's nomination as Duncan's successor wouldn't make a significant difference. But his speech continues (emphasis mine):

Stars, hide your fire,
Let not light see my black and deep desires,
The eye wink at the hand.

Again, these are not the words of a man who would patiently wait until kingship falls to him in a legal way. If the eye should overlook what the hand does, this implies a readiness to use violent means. In later scenes, we see him waver as his conscience gets in the way. What Lady Macbeth does is not giving him the idea of murder but (temporarily) overcome the resistance of his conscience.
Coming back to Macbeth's words at I.3.142–43:

If chance will have me king, why chance may crown me
Without my stir.

This does not mean he rejects violent means ("without my stir" = "without taking action") but that he is in the middle of an internal conflict. Why even mention that something might happen without taking action if he had not thought about taking action?
It is not legal succession that puts Macbeth in a conflicted state of mind, since that would not conjure up a "horrid image" or provoke "horrible imaginings". What he is in conflict about but has not quite convinced himself to do is the murder of Duncan.

References

Shakespeare: Macbeth. Edited by Eric Rasmussen and Jonathan Bate. The RSC Shakespeare. Macmillan, 2009. (This edition contains a section on various productions from the 20th and early 21st centuries, including an interview with Jonathan Pryce, Sinéad Cusack and Adrian Noble about the 1986–87 RSC production.)
Shakespeare: Macbeth. Edited by A. R. Braunmuller. The New Cambridge Shakespeare. Cambridge University Press, 1997.


Notes
[1] Duncan addresses Macbeth in Act I, scene 4 with "O worthiest cousin!" but this doesn't need to imply kinship: in Act 1, scene 3, Banquo calls Ross and Angus "cousins". However, Macbeth describes himself as Duncan's kinsman in Act I, scene 7.

"These are not the words of someone who wanted to patiently wait until Duncan's death" - This is immediately after he has been named the Thane of Cawdor without taking any action such as killing the previous holder of that title. Wouldn't a more natural interpretation of those lines be that since he was granted the Cawdor title "without my stir", the title of king may fall into his posession in the same way? I don't see how those lines don't mean "I may become king the same way I became the thane of Cawdor - without doing anything".

I agree with @Mithical; without my stir implies that Macbeth can become king without taking any action himself.

@Mithical That does not prove he has not thought about murdering Duncan, only that he has not quite convinced himself to do it and that he might become king without violence. I have updated my answer to explain this and have also added that Macbeth knew that the legal road was not open to him.
